# Burgers' equation with viscosity: modulational analysis and energy estimates for large data

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I think my question applies to many PDE that admit stationary solutions or travelling waves. I will simply describe the setting that I am more familiar with, but the technique is standard and applies to several models. The rough question is: "How to obtain the estimates on the perturbation of the stationary solution in the case where the perturbation is large, and the modulation parameter is not uniquely defined?"

---

Consider the viscous Burgers' equation in $\mathbb R$ with a forcing term:
$$ 
\begin{cases}
v_t-v_{xx}=(v^2)_x +f_x, & (x,t)\in \mathbb R\times [0,\infty) \\ v(x,0)=v_0(x), & x\in\mathbb R,
\end{cases}
$$
with kink-like boundary conditions at infinity: $v_0-\tanh(x)\in L^2(\mathbb R)$. The function $\tanh(x)$ is special because it is a stationary solution of the equation, together with all its translations. The only thing to take care of is the fact that $\tanh(x)\rightarrow \pm 1$ exponentially as $x\to\pm\infty$, and $\partial_x \tanh(x)=\operatorname{sech}^2(x)$. The forcing term $f$ lies in $L^2(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty)).$

The equation is globally well-posed in the affine space $L^2(\mathbb R)+\tanh$ by standard arguments.

---

Now, assume that the forcing term $f$ is small enough in $L^2(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty))$, and that the initial profile is a small perturbation of some translation of $\tanh$, i.e., $|v_0|_{L^2}$ is small enough, where
$$ |z|_{L^2}:=\min_{\gamma\in \mathbb R}\|z-\tanh(x-\gamma)\|_{L^2}. $$
Then, it is possible to prove that the quantity $|v(t)|_{L^2}$ is uniformly small on $[0,\infty)$, and in particular there exists a function $\alpha:[0,\infty)\mapsto \mathbb R$ such that $v=w+\tanh(x-\alpha(t))$ with the estimates
$$ \|w\|_{L^\infty_tL^2_x}+\|w_x\|_{L^2_tL^2_x}\lesssim \|w_0\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2_tL^2_x}.\label{1}\tag{1} $$
The function $\alpha$ is often called *modulation parameter* and what it is roughly meant to do is describe the "position" of the stationary solution that approximates $v$ best. In other words, we see $v$ as a perturbation of $\tanh(x-\alpha)$.

> *Proof (sketch)*. To show that, the basic argument uses some modulational analysis: call $w(x,t):=v(x,t)-\tanh(x-\alpha(t))$, where we fix $\alpha(t)$ using the orthogonality condition
> $$ \int_{\mathbb R}\operatorname{sech}^2(x-\alpha(t))w(x,t)\,dx=0 \quad\forall t\geq 0.\label{2}\tag{2} $$
> ($\alpha(t)$ is uniquely detemined by $v(t)$ thanks to the implicit function theorem if $|v(t)|_{L^2}$ is small enough). In this case, the function $w$ satisfies
> $$ 
> w_t-w_{xx}-2(\tanh(x-\alpha)w)_x=(w^2)_x+f_x+\alpha'\operatorname{sech}^2(x-\alpha).\label{3}\tag{3}
> $$
> Multiplying by $w$ and integrating in space (as for the usual energy estimates) we obtain
> $$ \frac 12\frac d{dt}\|w(t)\|_{L^2}+Q_\alpha(w)\leq\|f(t)\|_{L^2_x}\|w_x\|_{L^2}, $$
> where the last term vanishes thanks to the orthogonality condition \eqref{2} the term $(w^2)_x$ vanishes when tested against $w$, and $Q$ is the quadratic form
> $$ Q_\alpha(w):=\int_{\mathbb R}w_x^2-\operatorname{sech}^2(x-\alpha)w^2\,dx. $$
> Moreover (there is some work to do to show this) one can prove that, if $w$ satisfies the orthogonality condition \eqref{2}, then
> $$ Q_\alpha(w)\geq \frac{1}{2}\|w_x\|_{L^2}. $$
> Thus, integrating in time, we get the nice estimate
> $$ \|w\|_{L^\infty_tL^2_x}+\|w_x\|_{L^2_tL^2_x}\lesssim \|w_0\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2_tL^2_x}. $$

---

Now, if you made it alive until here, I really cannot thank you enough. My problem is:

**Question:** How to prove estimate \eqref{1} for arbitrary, large data $v_0$ and $f$? Is it even possible with a continuous parameter $\alpha$? If not, what if $\alpha$ is allowed to be discontinuous?

The main problem is that $\alpha(t)$ is not uniquely determined by the orthogonality condition \eqref{2} if the solution is large in the $|\cdot|_{L^2}$ norm. This leads to the fact, for instance, that the function $\alpha$ a priori is not necessarily continuous. If I knew that $\alpha$ satisfying \eqref{2} exists and is continuous, then I think I can prove the statement in a similar way by approximation, but I don't know how to prove that such a function $\alpha$ is continuous. In fact, if I pick $\alpha$ arbitrarily, it is perfectly possible to have something non-continuous. In the small data case, the continuity of $\alpha$ follows from equations \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}:

> *Sketch*. Differentiating \eqref{2} in $t$ and substituting $w_t$ using \eqref{3}, one obtains:
> $$ |\alpha'(t)| \left |\int_{\mathbb R}\operatorname{sech}^2(x-\alpha)[\operatorname{sech}^2-w_x]dx\right|\leq\dots, $$
> where the right hand side has good terms.

I feel like this issue is typical of modulational analysis for large data, but I have no idea how to treat this situation.

Comment: Have you looked at the works by Kevin Zumbrun? Especially https://community.ams.org/journals/qam/2011-69-01/S0033-569X-2011-01221-6/S0033-569X-2011-01221-6.pdf The Green's function/semigroup approach works for large perturbations. It even works for travelling waves with stochastic forcing, so it should also work for your equation. However, you will always need bounds on $v_0$ and $f$ in your proof (but in practice, they may be large).